# storing Datetime in MySQL database

Tags: mysql

I will be getting datetime from JsonFile in "2019-05-03T06:45:06.000+0000" this format. I want to put this into DB.

I tried using datetime datatype in MySQL table. Its not working.

```
create table employee(
    empId varchar(15),
    requestorId varchar(15),
    profile int ,
    createdTime datetime,
    reqId int
    );
insert into employee values("x","y",1,2019-05-03T06:45:06.000+0000,2);
```

> Error executing INSERT statement. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':45:06.000+0000,1)' at line 1 - Connection: Connection 1: 87ms

Answer (score 0):

Use `STR_TO_DATE`, which can convert an input date *string* into a bona fide MySQL datetime value:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('2019-05-03T06:45:06.000+0000', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s.%f+0000');
```

The format mask used here is `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s.%f+0000`.  Of note, the `%f` term matches fractional seconds.  In the case of your timestamp, there are three places of fractional precision.

Comment: @AlekhyaIdupulapati Please find the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a6edaa6e77652086e2ed3ed8ed3dbb67) based on Tim's answer.

Comment: @AlekhyaIdupulapati If you are doing a completely manual insert, then you will have to clean up the timestamp manually as well.  In that case, you should be inserting `'2019-05-03 06:45:06'`.